# String Search & replacement

Tags: c#, string

I have a string "JohnMarkMarkMark"

I want to replace the "Mark" with "Tom" with two cases

In  first case i want to replace only first occurance of "Mark" Result will be: "JohnTomMarkMark"
 In the second case i want to replace all the occurance of "Mark" Result will be: "JohnTomTomTom"

Please suggest
Thnaks

Comment: I am trying to find out the index of the string in the given string.Then will look to replace the string

Comment: Can You share the code you have written?

Comment: As it is my project code, i can not share it

Comment: that's now how this works. Nobody is asking you to share a trade secret. A string manipulation is no trade secret. You've boiled down the problem to its essence, you can do the same to attempts to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string data = "JohnMarkMarkMark";
string resultOne = new Regex("Mark").Replace(data,  "Tom", 1);
string resultAll = data.Replace("Mark", "Tom");
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx), [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) and [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0wkb0y3w.aspx).

For the second case, use [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

(1) is:

```
var inString = "TestMarkMarkMark";

var lookFor = "Mark";
var replaceWith = "Tom";
var length = lookFor.Length;
var first = inString.IndexOf(lookFor);
var newString = inString.Substring(0, first) + replaceWith + inString.Substring(first + length);
```

Which could be optimized, but I've expanded it out so it's easy to follow.

(2) is trivial - just do `inString.Replace("Mark", "Tom");`

Answer (score 0):

for case 1 try this

```
            string s = "JohnMarkMarkMark";
            Regex x = new Regex("Mark");
            MatchCollection m = x.Matches(s);
            if (m!=null && m.Count > 0)
            {
                s = s.Remove(m[0].Index, m[0].Length);
                s = s.Insert(m[0].Index,"Tom");
            }
```

for case 2 try `s = s.Replace("Mark","Tom");`